# Removing elements from one list from another, but not that value entirely

Tags: python, list, partitioning

I have a project where I must partition 2 lists according to the length of the parameter listA, the numbers must be in ascending order and the rest of the elements go into list B..

```
def partitionLists(listA, listB, largerFirst=False):
if largerFirst == False:
    sortedA = []
    listCombination = listA + listB
    listCombination.sort()
    for i in range(len(listA)):
        if listCombination[i] <= listCombination[i + 1]:
            sortedA.append(listCombination[i])
```

All I now need is to remove the elements that are in listA from sorted list but not entirely, e.g. List A is [1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5], and the total list is [1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 34, 45, 56, 65, 432, 543, 723], so I want to return a list with just [5, 6, 7, 7, 34, 45, 56, 65, 432, 543, 723], but if I try the conventional methods of removing common elements, it will also remove the 5 in the second list. Sorry if it seems difficult to understand because of my explanation but I hope I've gotten my point across

Comment: the "conventional" methods from duplicate questions will only remove 2 of the 5's which appears to be exactly what you want

Comment: show what are you doing for removing elements?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using an iterator on the first list that will tell you which elements of the second one to skip (assuming both lists are sorted):

```
def removeList(listA,listB):
    iterA  = iter(listA)
    valueA = next(iterA,None)
    result = []
    for valueB in listB:
        if valueB == valueA:
            valueA = next(iterA,None)
        else:
            result.append(valueB)
    return result
```

Output:

```
a = [1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
b = [1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 34, 45, 56, 65, 432, 543, 723]
c = removeList(a,b)

print(c) 

# [5, 6, 7, 7, 34, 45, 56, 65, 432, 543, 723]
```

[EDIT] If there can be numbers in listA that are not present in listB, the method needs to be adjusted in order to skip these values:

```
def removeList(listA,listB):
    iterA  = iter(listA)
    valueA = next(iterA,None)
    result = []
    for valueB in listB:
        while valueA is not None and valueA < valueB:
            valueA = next(iterA,None) # skip values in listA that are not in listB
        if valueB == valueA:
            valueA = next(iterA,None)
        else:
            result.append(valueB)
    return result

a = [1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 8]
b = [1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 34, 45, 56, 65, 432, 543, 723]
c = removeList(a,b)

print(c)

# [5, 6, 7, 7, 34, 45, 56, 65, 432, 543, 723]
```

Comment: yes ty that worked perfectly, never used an iterator before, will definitely look into this, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the example you provided, it seems as though it would be better to loop through your larger list to see if any of those elements are in your smaller list. If not, you can append them into an empty list. By your question, I am not sure which list needs to be sorted, but you can sort the list before or after. It shouldn't change your ability to append the elements into your empty list.

Comment: Yeah that would work too I guess I was too tunnel-visioned on sorting through the smaller list and checking if their indexes were equal and removing them if they were